# How To Create Global Filter in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

After my login my site url (mock url) is `http://mysubdomain.Domain.com/Dashboard` When I added `http://www.mysubdomain.Domain.com/Dashboard` it redirect to my login page .How can I avoid this using Global Filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of check that your domain has support for wild card.
- If you used for based authentication than there is issue related to FormAuthentication cookie domain.
  that cookie has to domain like = "*.domain.com" like this.
  IN web.config

> `<httpCookies domain=".domain.com"/>`